# Count and sort co-occurence matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scipy

I have a co-occurrence matrix in pandas. How do I get the co-occurence values of all the combinations, sorted descending without looping?
(I didn't write the values on the other side of the diagonal, but they are there, and hold mirrored values)

Input:

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F
A 0  1  0  1  2  0
B    0  3  1  1  1
C       0  1  8  9
D          0  2  6
E             0  9
F                0
```

Output:

```
CF  9
EF  9
CE  8
DF  6
BC  3
AE  2
DE  2
AB  1
AD  1
BD  1
BE  1
BF  1
CD  1
AC  0
AF  0
```

Comment: Hurtful, but useful. Thank you!

Comment: It's not intended to be, but instead a reliable source of information on *why* we downvote a question, so you as the asker is not left wondering why no one wants to help, and can ask a better question later.

Comment: Also as a side note, if you update the question with an attempt, I probably will remove the downvote.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "attempt" though.. Should I write what I've tried to do before?

Comment: "I tried this code, and it gave me X result. I expected/wanted Y result." Etc. And if you're really savvy, "I think the problem has to do with Z, but I'm not sure."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
i, j = np.triu_indices(len(df), 1)

pd.Series(
    df.values[i, j], df.index[i] + df.index[j]
).sort_values(ascending=False)

EF    9
CF    9
CE    8
DF    6
BC    3
DE    2
AE    2
CD    1
BF    1
BE    1
BD    1
AD    1
AB    1
AF    0
AC    0
dtype: object
```

---

**Setup**

```
txt = """\
  A  B  C  D  E  F
A 0  1  0  1  2  0
B    0  3  1  1  1
C       0  1  8  9
D          0  2  6
E             0  9
F                0"""

df = pd.read_fwf(pd.io.common.StringIO(txt), index_col=0).fillna('')
df

   A  B  C  D  E  F
A  0  1  0  1  2  0
B     0  3  1  1  1
C        0  1  8  9
D           0  2  6
E              0  9
F                 0
```

Comment: Thanks! So I modified the code to: coocc.stack().pipe(
    lambda s: s.set_axis(s.index.map('_and_'.join), inplace=False)
).astype(int).sort_values(ascending=False). But is there a way to not duplicate the row-columns? I mean so only AB is displayed. Not both AB and BA?

Comment: Updated assuming those are empty spaces.

Comment: They are not empty, but a mirror of the other side. Meaning AB is the same as BA

Comment: Updated again. @AnonX

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through row and columns using `combinations` from `itertools` and add to the list.

```
from itertools import combinations
explode_list = []
_ = [explode_list.append([r + c, df.loc[r][c]]) for r, c in combinations(df.columns, 2)]
```

**Output**

```
[['AB', 1],
 ['AC', 0],
 ...
]
```